# How to add millisecond to this type of simple code of Stopwatch. Java NETBEANS Jframe

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, timer, jframe

The program is done but I want to add milliseconds to it to be a part of the real stopwatch. I don't own this code but I just revised it. I used Jframe (drag and drop). House, minutes, and seconds it would be complete having milliseconds to it in if/else. but how?

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Stopwatch extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static int h = 0, m = 0, s = 0;

    private Timer t;

    public Stopwatch() {

         initComponents();
        this.setTitle ("Timer");
        this.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        setIcon ();
    }


    int i = 0;
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        JframeP = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        timerP = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        hours = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        colon1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        minutes = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        colon2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        seconds = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        start = new javax.swing.JButton();
        pause = new javax.swing.JButton();
        reset = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        JframeP.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        JframeP.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 300));

        timerP.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        timerP.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));
        timerP.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(552, 160));

        hours.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 0, 130)); // NOI18N
        hours.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        hours.setText("00");

        colon1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 0, 130)); // NOI18N
        colon1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        colon1.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        colon1.setText(":");

        minutes.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 0, 130)); // NOI18N
        minutes.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        minutes.setText("00");

        colon2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 0, 130)); // NOI18N
        colon2.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        colon2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
        colon2.setText(":");

        seconds.setFont(new java.awt.Font("DS-Digital", 0, 130)); // NOI18N
        seconds.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 102));
        seconds.setText("00");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout timerPLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(timerP);
        timerP.setLayout(timerPLayout);
        timerPLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            timerPLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, timerPLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(37, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(hours)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(colon1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(minutes)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(colon2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(seconds)
                .addGap(33, 33, 33))
        );
        timerPLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            timerPLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(hours, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 156, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(colon1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(minutes, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(colon2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(seconds, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        start.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        start.setText("START");
        start.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(115, 50));
        start.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                startMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        start.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                startActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        pause.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        pause.setText("PAUSE");
        pause.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(115, 50));
        pause.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                pauseMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        reset.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Arial", 0, 14)); // NOI18N
        reset.setText("RESET");
        reset.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(115, 50));
        reset.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                resetMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout JframePLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(JframeP);
        JframeP.setLayout(JframePLayout);
        JframePLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            JframePLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(JframePLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addComponent(start, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(82, 82, 82)
                .addComponent(pause, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(reset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(46, 46, 46))
            .addGroup(JframePLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(23, 23, 23)
                .addComponent(timerP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        JframePLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            JframePLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(JframePLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(27, 27, 27)
                .addComponent(timerP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(JframePLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(start, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 45, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(pause, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(reset, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(34, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(JframeP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(JframeP, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    private void startMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
      t=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

            if (s < 59) {
                s++;
                String sec = (s < 10 ? "0" : "") + s;
                seconds.setText("" + sec);
            } else {
                s = 0;
                seconds.setText("00");

                if (m < 59) {
                    m++;
                    String min = (m < 10 ? "0" : "") + m;
                    minutes.setText("" + min);
                } else {
                    h = 0;
                    minutes.setText("00");

                    h++;
                    String hour = (h < 10 ? "0" : "") + h;
                    hours.setText("" + hour);
                }
            }

         } 
      });

      t.start();
        start.setEnabled (false);

    }                                  


    private void pauseMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
     if (i == 0) {
            t.stop();
            i = 1;
            pause.setText("CONTINUE");
        } else {
            t.start();
            i = 0;
            pause.setText("PAUSE");}
    }                                  

    private void resetMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   
        t.stop();
        hours.setText("00"); h = 0;
        minutes.setText("00"); m = 0;
        seconds.setText("00"); s = 0;
        i = 0;
        pause.setText("PAUSE");
        start.setEnabled (true);
    }                                  

    private void startActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      

    }                                     

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        }



    public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Stopwatch().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel JframeP;
    private javax.swing.JLabel colon1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel colon2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel hours;
    private javax.swing.JLabel minutes;
    private javax.swing.JButton pause;
    private javax.swing.JButton reset;
    private javax.swing.JLabel seconds;
    private javax.swing.JButton start;
    private javax.swing.JPanel timerP;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private void setIcon() {
        setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(getClass().getResource("Stopwatch.png")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you initiate your timer object

```
 t=new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
    // stuff
 }
```

you are telling the timer, to wait for 1000 milliseconds then do the actionPerformed. so to make it do your action performed every milisecond you could simply change that to

```
t=new Timer(1,new ActionListener() 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        // stuff
}
```

After which you can introduce similar code to what already exists for handling the milliseconds,

hint there are 1000 milliseconds in a second, so the code would be similar to the seconds handling except instead of incrementing the minutes every 60 seconds you would be incrementing the seconds every 1000 milliseconds.

**edit:**
since you didn't write the code if you're wondering where the timer is initiated its within the method:

```
private void startMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {...}
```